# What does the error unexpected token 'public' mean?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am a beginner in Apex and I need your help. What I am trying to do is creating a class that returns an array of formatted strings. The class has as a parameter the number of strings and it returns the array of strings formatted as:

> Test 0, Test 1,  ...Test n

The error I get is:

> unexpected token 'public (line 1).

There might be more than one error in my code, if yes please feel free to let me know. 
Thank you in advance!

```
public class StringArrayTest {
        public static void generateStringArray(Integer n){
            //List<String> stringArray = new List<String>();
            for(Integer i=0; i<n; i++){
                List<String>stringArray = new List<String>{'Test '+i};

            }
           return stringArray[]; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with the code you have posted. When I tried this out I didn't get the error you mentioned, but here are the things to fix and get your code working:

- The method should declare a return value of `List<String>`
- Uncomment the line to initialize your list before the loop.
- Return just the variable itself, no need to have the brackets. It's already a list.

Here is working code:

```
public class StringArrayTest {
    public static List<String> generateStringArray(Integer n){
        List<String> stringArray = new List<String>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < n; i++){
            stringArray.add('Test ' + i);
        }
        return stringArray; 
    }
}
```